# Wpf Rounded corners progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I'm trying to make a simple progress bar with rounded corners.

This is my xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100"  Height="50"  Value="50" Name="pbStatus" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Foreground="#336699"  />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=pbStatus, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to look for the `Border-Radius` property.... but i just find it.
Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF rounded corner textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779777/wpf-rounded-corner-textbox)

Comment: This is not duplicate, the one you referred to speaks about textbox and not progressbar.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From **Visual Studio Designer** Right Click on the `ProgressBar` > Edit Template > Edit a Copy,
In the Generated Style add `CornerRadius` to the `Border` and set the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` in the filling Rectangles :

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="30"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" />
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Indicator" ClipToBounds="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Animation" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how to Edit a template in WPF !! Thanks a lot lot !

Comment: RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" solved my issue with progress indicator overriding corner radius^^

Answer (score 4):

Put a border inside and set the corner radius property of the border instead. Here is the link describing this
[progressbar bar style right radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406224/progressbar-bar-style-right-radius)

Comment: that's the point... The progressbar doesnt even have the `Corner-Radius` property..